# 80's TV show Pilot man with electrical powers... NOT Misfits of Science.. solo guy

Tags: story-identification

Anyone remember this one?  Name?

All I remember was he told his mother was pregnant with him and was struck by lightning and died right after giving birth to him. He worked on a farm. He was normal until struck by lightning himself. Then he developed his powers of electricity, but he couldn't really control it. People find out about him and are after him. Someone he meets knew about him and what happened to his mother, and gives him a watch that helps him regulate his power.

That's all I can really remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly *[The Power Within](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081365/)* aka *Power Man*, a 1979 film and TV pilot. It doesn't fit all of your criteria, but it does have a guy with electrical powers, pursued by people who want to use him, and a wristwatch to control it.

[image: Movie Poster] [image: VHS Cover]

> A young man (Art Hindle) suffers a lightning strike on a dark and stormy night. Instead of dying, he absorbs the lightning's electrical energy into his body, losing consciousness. He awakens in a hospital, only to learn that the accident changed both his body and his life, as he knew it, forever. Now he can discharge electricity from his body at will. The government coerces the young man into becoming an operative, and his handler gives him a wristwatch that is not really a wristwatch, but rather is a device that allows him to control precisely his electrical discharges. The hook is that now that the lightning strike "charged" his body, he has no choice but to re-charge the electrical energy stored in his body on a regular basis, or he will die.

This short clip has an example of his electrical powers at the end:

Apparently a major draw for the film was Art Scholl's Super Chipmunk stunt plane.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my delayed response. I actually forgot about this post, because it never notified me. I was just doing a Google search again for the show after watching "Misfits of Science". LOL   Thank you very much for responding back and the info. I'm checking it out now on YouTube, I think this might it!  :D   I hope you're doing well.
Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about *[Powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powder_(film))*.

> Jeremy "Powder" Reed (Sean Patrick Flanery) is a young albino man who has incredible intellect and is able to sense the thoughts of the people around him. Jeremy's brain possesses a powerful electromagnetic charge, which causes electrical objects to function abnormally when he is around them, particularly when he becomes emotional. The electromagnetic charge also prevents hair from growing on his body.
>
> **Jeremy's mother was struck by lightning while pregnant with him; she died shortly after the strike, but Jeremy survived.** His father disowned him shortly after his premature birth, and he was raised by his grandparents. Jeremy lived in the basement and **worked on their farm,** [...]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should read [answer]; in general you should provide the necessary details for people to understand this is a match, and not require them to do their own research.  All it really requires is to include a quote from the plot summary of the Wikipedia page instead of just a link to it.